# Retaining search property in Advanced search box

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search, advanced-search

I have configured my Advance search box to take 3 newly created managed properties. Also i have exported the advanced search box to a different page where i have placed search results and navigation. I have configured for the results page to be  the same so that the search and  results happen on same page. But a problem i am facing is as soon as i select property with the operator and value and press search the selected properties and values vanish. The results are displayed but the user has no way of seeing what was searched. Can i retain the selected properties and values even after the results are displayed?

before search
[image]

after search
[image]